# fastest way to fit a quadratic polynomial to rolling window values using dask?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, dask

I have a large dataset of 36k x 3k (rows, columns), I want to fit a quadratic polynomial to the values of a 1D rolling window (size=n) centered at each value along every column. I know this a very costly operation and would like to do this as fast as I can.
After creating dask arrays chuncked (500 x 3k), I have tried obtaining the coefficients of each quadratic fit using two methods:

1. With the `scipy.generic_filter()`,
   `generic_filter(scene2, function=curvature, footprint=footprint, extra_arguments=(x,)).compute()`

using a footprint that only considers the values along a column. The function used with this filter is the following,

```
def curvature(neigh, x):
    c, b, a = Polynomial.fit(x, neigh, 2).coef
    return 2*a
```

However, I do not think that I am parallelizing well (and it takes a very long time to compute).

The other attempt I have made (which failed) was using the following function:

```
def window_curve_fit(arr, deg=2, size=3, x_step=0.01,**kwargs):
    #
    values= []
  
    # create x
    x = np.linspace(x_step, size*x_step, size)
    
    # process each element
    for y in sliding_window_view(arr, size, **kwargs):
        c,b,a= [Polynomial.fit(x, y, deg).coef]
        values += [2*a]

    return values
```

And using the following line,

`rslt= da.map_blocks(window_curve_fit, scene2, 2, 5, 0.01, dtype= np.float32, axis=1).compute()`

this last one has given me the following error which I do not really understand.

```
...

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'chunks'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried working with `scipy.signal.savgol_coeff` and `scipy.signal.savgol_filter`?

Comment: Hi @iadriaens, I am not familiar with this functions. But it appears that it is exactly what I was looking for, and it is really fast! Thank you!